# How to bottom center a span inside a list item

Tags: android, html, css, webkit, alignment

I think this is already discussed somewhere but I couldn't find it :(

So as the title questions it; how to bring the `span`, inside the `li`, to be **centred, and bottom aligned** with a cross browser css rules (target is *Webkit browser inside Android device*)?

<kbd>**[DEMO at Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Xqx0vjI1OMY3m3gpVUNh?p=preview)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help?

```css
.page--game-core_bottom .tabs li {
    position: relative; /* Set as a reference point */
}

.page--game-core_bottom .tabs li span{
    /* margin-top: 10px; */
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;       /* These three lines   */
    right: 0;      /* keeps the spans     */
    margin: auto;  /* center horizontally */
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/aK8f4/1/)**

Comment: Tanks Hashem for the extra explanations!

Answer (score 1):

use

```
li.a span,li.b span,li.c span {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/aK8f4/)

[**centered span**](http://jsfiddle.net/aK8f4/4/)

Comment: This is close to what I wanted, Thanks! The span is bottom positioned but it still needs to be center :(

Comment: @numediaweb : added..please check!! :)

Comment: Thanks for your answers; the solution you offered works too! +1

Answer (score 0):

This is a CSS question, not really anything android related, you should find the webkit on android is pretty capable (it hasn't really caused any problems for my own webviews).

To align something to the bottom of a container the container (your li) has to implement relative or absolute positioning and be a block item (display: block; or inline-block though that has some issues). The span then needs to be absolute with bottom: 0;

(Please bear in mind that changing your li to a block-type item could affect some other parts of your layout though)

For centering either make your span fill the width then text align center, use margin:0 auto; (if you've made the span into a block with a set width as well) or use the left and right 0 trick

Comment: Thanks Nick. By specifying target as android browser, I try to eliminate solutions with new css3 rules that are not supported in old Webkit devices and also, the solutions that involve javascript solutions. developing for the browser in those tinny devices is quite challenging :)

Answer (score 0):

Complementing the answer by Nick, I'd say that once your `<span>` is absolute positioned you can set both `left` and `right` properties to 0 and give it a fixed width that it'll automagically be aligned in the center.